# Animation doesn't show when application starts

Tags: android, animation, fragment, parent

I have a main activity which keeps 2 fragments.

On the first fragment i call an animation from the main activity.

If i call it from a button it animates and everything is ok

If i try to call it automatically (like    if(x>3) animate()) it doesn't show the animation at all and in addition if i push the button it continues not to showing the animation. the code is below

Parent

```
public void showAnimation()
{
    AnimationSet as = new AnimationSet(true);

    Animation up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getBaseContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
    up.setStartOffset(2000);
    Animation down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getBaseContext(), R.anim.slide_down);
    down.setStartOffset(6000);
    as.addAnimation(up);
    as.addAnimation(down);

    Log.v("FFF","ok");
    test.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    test.startAnimation(as);
    test.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

Child

```
 if(!settings.getBoolean(BADGE_D7, false)){
        if (days >= 7){
            days7.setImageResource(R.drawable.days7);
            Log.v("FFF","done");
            parent.showAnimation();
        }
    }
```

and in the constructor of the child i have

```
public Child(MainActivity p) {
    this.parent = p;
}
```

by the way the log messages are shown up the only problem is the animation. What is the problem??

Comment: Make sure that you're running showAnimation() from the UI thread.

Comment: i use the same parent.showAnimation() from the button and it works fine. It only doesn't when i put it to animate automatically :/
Maybe i should do something like wait for all the elements to be in their place and after do the animation , but i don't know exactly how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Well, i kinda found out a solution, it's not the best but it works.

First i put all the code in the child activity and i use it from there. I access the textView from the child and i added a treeObserver

```
test = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.test1);
     ViewTreeObserver vto = test.getViewTreeObserver();
     vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                ready = true;
                return true;
            }
        });
```

and I edited the showAnimation() like this:

```
public void showAnimation()
{
    as = new AnimationSet(true);

    Animation up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getActivity(), R.anim.slide_up);
    Animation down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getActivity(), R.anim.slide_down);
    down.setStartOffset(4000);
    as.addAnimation(up);
    as.addAnimation(down);

    Log.v("FFF","ok");
    while(!ready){}  //Added this line
    test.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    test.startAnimation(as);
    test.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

so while the TextView isn't in place it is stucks in a loop until everything is ok.

Comment: It's not clear to me when you are calling showAnimation(). I'm guessing that you're calling to early, perhaps in the onCreate method of an Activity? Try calling it later in the Activity/Fragment lifecycle, like in onResume(). Then you shouldn't need the ViewTreeObserver.

Comment: yea i was calling it on the onCreate(). It works now , i'll try to put in on the onResume to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had a view that I declared at the end of my layout to keep its Z index above its siblings. I had to touch the page to make the animation work.

So I set the Z index again through Java and it worked.

```
view.bringToFront();
```